# Git index предназначение

Tags: git

Добрый день! Прочитал статьи про индекс и все равно не понимаю смысл индекса. Зачем такое усложнение необходимо? SVN справлялся и без него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Индекс это временный буфер. Git редко перемещает данные непосредственно между вашим проектом и его историей. Вместо этого Git сначала записывает данные в индекс, а уж затем копирует их из индекса по месту назначения.

Например, commit -a на самом деле двухэтапный процесс. Сначала слепок текущего состояния каждого из отслеживаемых файлов помещается в индекс. Затем слепок, находящийся в индексе, записывается в историю. Коммит без опции -a выполняет только второй шаг, и имеет смысл только после выполнения команд, изменяющих индекс, таких как git add.

Обычно мы можем не обращать внимания на индекс и делать вид, что взаимодействуем напрямую с историей. Но в данном случае мы хотим более тонкого контроля, поэтому управляем индексом. Мы помещаем слепок некоторых (но не всех) наших изменений в индекс, после чего окончательно записываем этот аккуратно сформированный слепок."

Но я, скажем, не заморачиваюсь с индексами.